# Error when using composer require-dev.mikey179/vfsStream is invalid

Tags: codeigniter, composer-php, codeigniter-3, amazon-lightsail

I am using Amazon LightSail and the CodeIgniter framework. Trying to install PhpSpreadsheet - https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation using

```
composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
```

However I then am greeted with

```
 [RuntimeException]
  require-dev.mikey179/vfsStream is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use mikey179/vfsstream instead.
```

I did the usual Googling but couldn't find anything specific.

When I run

```
composer.phar show
```

I get the error from above.

Comment: which php version are you installing onto?

Comment: also check this: https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream/issues/173

Comment: Please share more details about the current state of your `composer.json`. Also, which version of Composer are you using?

Comment: How do I find out the version? Every command I try and run, it fails with that error. I'm on Amazon LightSail...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You must have `mikey179/vfsStream` in your `composer.json` in `require-dev` section (as the problem is for `require-dev` and you are trying to do normal require).

Simply change the name of package to all lowercase characters.

Answer (score 12):

Just replace **mikey179/vfsStream** with **mikey179/vfsstream**

they need to be in lowercase

Comment: This has already been pointed out in several other answers.

Answer (score 6):

Make this "mikey179/vfsStream" package name to lowercase.

"mikey179/vfsStream" replace this to "mikey179/vfsstream"

Answer (score 3):

In your composer.json file look for mikey179/vfsStream and lowercase all its characters and make it mikey179/vfsstream

```
"require-dev": {
    "mikey179/vfsstream": "1.1.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.* || 5.*"
}
```

Comment: This helped me, thank you.