# How to fix error fzaninotto/Faker should not contain uppercase characters

Tags: composer-php

require.fzaninotto/Faker is invalid, it should not contain uppercase characters. Please use fzaninotto/faker instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when using composer require-dev.mikey179/vfsStream is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67437034/error-when-using-composer-require-dev-mikey179-vfsstream-is-invalid)

Answer (score 1):

> Please use fzaninotto/faker instead.

You have the answer in the message :)

Replace capital `F` with lowercase version `f`.