# CodeIgniter 3 - Composer Update Error - vfsstream

Tags: php, composer-php, codeigniter-3, vfs-stream

When running composer update for my CodeIgniter 3 project, I get the following error:

> 1. `> sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php`
> 2. `sed: 1: "vendor/mikey179/vfsstre ...": invalid command code v`
> 3. `Script sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1`

I have previously corrected the [uppercase error with vfsStream](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream/issues/173) <sup>*[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67437034/367456), [2](https://github.com/bovigo/vfsStream/issues/173)*</sup>.

Composer version: 2.3.9
Running on: Mac and Heroku-22

Composer.json extract from the CodeIgniter 3 framework:

```
"scripts": {
  "test:coverage": [
    "@putenv XDEBUG_MODE=coverage",
    "phpunit --color=always --coverage-text --configuration tests/travis/sqlite.phpunit.xml"
  ],
  "post-install-cmd": [
    "sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php"
  ],
  "post-update-cmd": [
    "sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Which Composer version are you using and in which shell/enviroment is that `post-update-cmd` event script executed?

Comment: Using Composer version 2.3.9. I get the same error when running on my local mac machine, but also when deploying to a heroku-22 stack. The composer.json file is the standard one from the Code Ignitor framework.

Comment: please see my answer, this is the case then. also the package in question must not need any such patches, try with the removal of the script.

Comment: And please add the relevant parts of your composer.json (those of which it may become clear how that script ended up in the composer.json in the first place) to the question (you can [edit]), it could be this could benefit from an update upstream in [tag:codeigniter-3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking about a *Composer Script* that has been configured in your project within the Composer configuration file named `composer.json` by default (you have not shared which configuration file (you have), so please bear with me I can only state the default one).

While Composer was executing that script it detected that the script did not run successfully (sometimes referred to as `EXIT_SUCCESS`).

Therefore Composer displays the error message about the fact and the script in question.

That is what you're seeing.

The resolution of that requires to look at the actual script and debug it. Otherwise it is always an option that you remove any scripts you don't want, e.g. because they don't work for you.

This is rather straight forward: Open the configuration file in question (`composer.json` by default), locate the *Scripts Section* and within it, the `post-update-cmd` entry. Fix or remove it.

If you have received this piece of code under a specific license or contract, consult it for your dedicated support options.

If you want to learn about the actual script command, consult the manual of the commands in use. Specifically the manual of `sed(1)` which emits the error message Composer echoes:

> 1. `sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php`
> 2. `sed: 1: "vendor/mikey179/vfsstre ...": invalid command code v`

You're (perhaps) running the Composer transaction on a Mac computer:

- [Invalid command code . - Using sed to replace characters inline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/663387/9340)

But that is only one of the many probabilities that may explain what `sed(1)` tells here, `composer(1)` only echoes that message.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error:

```
> sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php
sed: 1: "vendor/mikey179/vfsstre ...": invalid command code v
Script sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

and here is how I fix it:

1. open your composer.json
2. in the `post-update-cmd` section, replace this script:

```
"sed -i s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php"
```

3. with this script:

```
"sed -i .bak s/name{0}/name[0]/ vendor/mikey179/vfsstream/src/main/php/org/bovigo/vfs/vfsStream.php"
```